# VS Code no me deja escribir en el output

Tags: python, vscode

Estoy intentando hacer una agenda de contactos, previamente me dejaba interactuar con el output de manera que podía probar el código (e.g. Escribía 1, y me pedia datos, los procesaba y se repetía el proceso) sin embargo pasaron unos días y ahora no me permite escribir nada en el output. El código sigue siento el mismo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el código por si hay algún error:

```
def agregar_contacto():
    nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre del contacto: ")
    telefono = input("Ingrese el teléfono del contacto: ")
    correo = input("Ingrese el correo electrónico del contacto: ")
    agregar_contacto_db(nombre, telefono, correo)
    print("Contacto agregado exitosamente.")

def mostrar_contacto(nombre):
    contacto = mostrar_contacto_db(nombre)
    if contacto:
        print(f"Nombre: {contacto[0]}")
        print(f"Teléfono: {contacto[1]}")
        print(f"Correo electrónico: {contacto[2]}")
    else:
        print("Contacto no encontrado.")

def modificar_contacto(nombre):
    contacto = mostrar_contacto_db(nombre)
    if contacto:
        print(f"Contacto actual: {contacto}")
        nuevo_nombre = input("Ingrese el nuevo nombre del contacto: ")
        nuevo_telefono = input("Ingrese el nuevo teléfono del contacto: ")
        nuevo_correo = input("Ingrese el nuevo correo electrónico del contacto: ")
        modificar_contacto_db(nombre, nuevo_nombre, nuevo_telefono, nuevo_correo)
        print("Contacto modificado exitosamente.")
    else:
        print("Contacto no encontrado.")

def eliminar_contacto(nombre):
    eliminar_contacto_db(nombre)
    print("Contacto eliminado exitosamente.")

# Menú principal
while True:

    print("---- AGENDA DE CONTACTOS ----")
    print("1. Agregar contacto")
    print("2. Mostrar contacto")
    print("3. Modificar contacto")
    print("4. Eliminar contacto")
    print("5. Salir")
    
    opcion = input("Seleccione una opción: ")
    
    if opcion == "1":
        agregar_contacto()
    elif opcion == "2":
        nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre del contacto a mostrar: ")
        mostrar_contacto(nombre)
    elif opcion == "3":
        nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre del contacto a modificar: ")
        modificar_contacto(nombre)   #no puedo encontrar la forma de que muestre los contactos que se guardaron previos en la agenda
    elif opcion == "4":
        nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre del contacto a eliminar: ")
        eliminar_contacto(nombre)
    elif opcion == "5":
        break
    else:
        print("Opción inválida. Por favor, seleccione una opción válida.")
```

Comment: mirate esta pregunta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671747/visual-studio-code-input-function-in-python, prueba la opcion Ctrl+Shift+d y selecciona Integrated Terminal/Console